# Android - Make StatusBar transparent on a specific fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-statusbar

I have a ViewPager with several fragments, his layout includes only the ViewPager with a TabLayout, nothing else.
And one specific fragment (in view pager) which has a coordinator layout with collapsing toolbar (on the right)

[image]

What I want to do is to set the StatusBar transparent only on the right fragment. Just imagine I want to move the picture on the right fragment completely top
I've tried several methods like `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` , make the ViewPager fullscreen (it wasn't what I expected) or modify application theme. But this is a specific situation that I can't find any solution. Thanks for any ideas.